# Android studio cannot debug Fragment

Tags: android, linux, debugging, android-fragments

I have an AppCompatDialogFragment fragment, I set different breakpoints, tried all lifecycle methods such as onCreate and onCreateDialog but it is not stopping on any one them. Normal activities can be debugged normally. This is an example of my implementation :

```
public class SettingsDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
   // Implementation
}
```

I also set some logcat logs and that is working fine, so basically everything works but debugger is not stopping at any breakpoints within the fragment.

I am using Linux, could this be the reason? Is there a specific configuration setting on Android Studio to debug fragments?

Comment: Have you set minifyEnabled false in app.build file

Comment: After 'minifyEnabled false' its working fine

Comment: i got the same issue when debugging evaluate element get a message 'this@homefragment is not supported'.
Alse check the minifyEnabled is already false

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mahabub Karim for the solution. Indeed, the solution to my problem was commenting the debug section on the app.build, which had minifyEnabled. It also works by just commenting the produardFiles line aswell:

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: `minifyEnabled true` is complete non-sense for a debug build.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I think so now that I thing about it. However, I think that I had some problems when the app was on the store and the only way to figure out what was wrong was setting the minify, don't remember what was the problem, I think some static images were not displayed.

Comment: You can test problems with the store version by changing the "Build Variant" from debug to release